# Soft and Hard EM (Expectation Maximization)

Tags: fitting, expectation-maximization, unsupervised-learning

What is the difference between soft and hard expectation maximization?

EDIT: ok, i've found out this paper: http://ttic.uchicago.edu/~dmcallester/ttic101-07/lectures/em/em.pdf
that explain quite well the situations

Comment: You may need to explain what you mean by soft and hard EM, or provide a link.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on the paper you linked to, I would argue that the term EM usually refers to the "soft" version. The key distinction seems to be that instead of taking an expectation in the E-step, the "hard" version finds a mode.

A good explanation of the distinction is available in chapters 20-22 of David Mackay's book (which is [available online](http://www.inference.phy.cam.ac.uk/mackay/itila/)).

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you look at this: 
http://cogcomp.cs.illinois.edu/papers/SamdaniChRo12.pdf

There is a nice comparison in table 1.